Python Async Thread-safe Semaphore
I'm looking for a thread-safe implementation of a Semaphore I can use in Python.
The standard libraries asyncio.Semaphore isn't thread-safe.
The standard libraries threading.Semaphore doesn't have awaitable interface.
I am using sanic which has multiple threads (workers) but also an asynchronous loop on each thread. I want to be able to yield execution back to the event loop on each of the workers whenever it encounters a blocked semaphore, while it waits.
UPDATE: I meant to say process here, not threads. So these should be that Sanic splits across processes, and multiprocessing.Semaphore. I believe the answer given is still relevant to where I can apply a similar solution.

This question is similar to: Asyncio threadsafe primitives. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you are saying that you need a single semaphore instance to be used across all the threads, then create a threading.Semaphore instance and am async function acquire_semaphore such as the following:
import asyncio
import threading
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

executor = ThreadPoolExecutor()
semaphore = threading.Semaphore()

async def acquire_semaphore():
    """Make a threading.Semaphore awaitable."""

    def acquirer():
        semaphore.acquire()

    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    await loop.run_in_executor(executor, acquirer)

async def test():
    """Acquire and release a semaphore sharable across threads."""

    await acquire_semaphore()
    print('acquired')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    semaphore.release()  # This never blocks
    print('released')


def worker():
    asyncio.run(test())

def main():
    threads = [
        threading.Thread(target=worker)
        for _ in range(3)
    ]

    for thread in threads:
        thread.start()

    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Prints:
acquired
released
acquired
released
acquired
released


Try aiologic.Semaphore (I'm the creator of aiologic):
import asyncio

from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

from aiologic import Semaphore

semaphore = Semaphore()


async def work():
    async with semaphore:
        print("acquired")
        
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

    print("released")


with ThreadPoolExecutor(3) as executor:
    for _ in range(3):
        executor.submit(asyncio.run, work())

Prints:
acquired
released
acquired
released
acquired
released

Unlike Booboo's solution, it doesn't use an executor, so it doesn't have cancellation issues.
